# wordpress query posts with category names included

Tags: arrays, wordpress, post, categories

I am working on querying posts in wordpress and trying to get the category names along with it so I can put the query in an array to be quickly accessed without having to requery the server.  Is there a way to get posts and the category names in one query?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns all of the categories for a post by using $post->ID;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories

Comment: Right but is there a way to get the posts in a query and the category name with it?  Not just a list of categories.

Comment: @Dan just to confirm, you want every post with their categories? Remember posts can belong to more than one category. So that function i posted returns a list of categories the specified post belongs to.